# Not able to show items in recyclerview getting from viewModel

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have an editText and a button. When I click on the button the data from the edittext gets inserted into the database. On the save activity I have recyclerView which will show the items getting from the viewModel. I have put the observer to observer the data but it is not showing any item in the recuclerView.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NoteAdapter.OnItemClicked {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var btnAdd: Button
    private lateinit var etNote: EditText
    lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btn_add)
        etNote = findViewById(R.id.et_note)

        val mAdapter = NoteAdapter(this)

        recyclerView.apply {
            adapter = mAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        }

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application))[MyViewModel::class.java]

        viewModel.allNotes.observe(this, Observer {note->
            note?.let {
                mAdapter.submitList(it)
            }
        })

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
            addNote()
        }
    }

    override fun onClick(note: Notes) {
        viewModel.delete(note)
    }

    private fun addNote(){
        val note: String = etNote.text.toString()

        if(note.isNotEmpty()) {
            viewModel.insert(Notes(note))
            Toast.makeText(this, "$note inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter Class

```
class NoteAdapter(private val clickListener: OnItemClicked)
    : ListAdapter<Notes, NoteAdapter.MyViewHolder>(NoteComparator()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.note_item, parent, false)
        val viewHolder = MyViewHolder(view)

        viewHolder.ivDelete.setOnClickListener{
            clickListener.onClick(getItem(viewHolder.adapterPosition))
        }

        return viewHolder
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentNote = getItem(position)
        holder.apply {
            tvNoteItem.text = currentNote.note
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClicked{
        fun onClick(note: Notes)
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val tvNoteItem: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_note)
        val ivDelete: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_delete)
    }
    
    class NoteComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Notes>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Notes, newItem: Notes): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Notes, newItem: Notes): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel Class

```
class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: NotesRepository
    val allNotes : LiveData<List<Notes>>

    init {
        val dao = NoteDatabase.getDatabase(application).noteDao()
        repository = NotesRepository(dao)
        allNotes = repository.noteList
    }

    fun delete(note: Notes) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.delete(note)
    }

    fun insert(note: Notes) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insert(note)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heey Divyansh,

Analyzing your code I believe the problem is in your ViewModel. You are trying to change the property **allNotes**, which is a LiveData. You need mutable live data, so declare it like private because we can't expose a mutable property. And your allNotes property will receive the changes from this mutable property, like this:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val _allNotes = MutableLiveData<List<Notes>>(emptyList())
    val allNotes: LiveData<List<Notes>>
        get() = _allNotes

}
```

Then, update the mutable live data:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    // ...
    init {
        val dao = NoteDatabase.getDatabase(application).noteDao()
        repository = NotesRepository(dao)
        _allNotes.value = repository.noteList
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It is still not showing anything. I have done this to my viewmodel as you have said.
  `private val repository: NotesRepository
    private var _allNotes = MutableLiveData<List<Notes>>(emptyList())
    val allNotes: LiveData<List<Notes>>
        get() = _allNotes

    init {
        val dao = NoteDatabase.getDatabase(application).noteDao()
        repository = NotesRepository(dao)
        _allNotes.value = repository.noteList.value
    }`

Comment: Try to debug or use the log to see if you receive any value from this NoteRepository, please. So we can discard that the problem is there. Could you share your repository implementation with me?

Answer (score 0):

I have found why it is not displaying the items because the viewModel is not inserting the the data as I have used Dispatcher.IO in the viewModel scope.
I removed it and now it is inserting and showing the items.